# asp.net mvc - How to Pass multiple models

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, model-view-controller, ado.net

I have three tables `designation`, `department`, `employee`.

When I go to create employee page,I need to pass `designations` and `departments`for select input options in that page.

how can I pass those two models from asp.net controller as `Jsonresult`. I am using angularjs in client side.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public JsonResult GetData()
{
   var departments = //fetch department list;
   var designations = //fetch designations;
   return Json(new { departmentList= departments, designationList= designations});
}
```

You can access these in your `$http` calls as `result.designationList` and `result.departmentList`